# How to assign call argument to var and echo it in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to do this:

```
set kommune

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (DBLib.txt) DO (
    CALL :decryptLine "%%x"
)
GOTO:eof

:decryptLine
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ("%~1") do set argument=%%a & set value=%%b
set "argument=%argument:~0,-2%"
set "value=%value:~1%"
call:updateVar "%argument%" "%value%"
GOTO:EOF

:updateVar
IF "%~1" == "KommuneNavn" (
    ECHO "%~2"
    ECHO "KommuneNavn"
    set kommune=%~2
    ECHO kommune = "%kommune%" testhest
)
```

What it outputs:

```
"ABC Test Kommune"
"KommuneNavn"
"kommune = "" testhest"
```

How do i copy the value of the secont argument to the Variable "kommune"? And `Echo` it?

Edit 1: updated to exact code. "inside `IF`"

Comment: running your code with `value` set to `valuestring` produces the line `kommune = "valuestring" testhest` - not as you've reported. Please make sure that you've copied and pasted your exact code (**including** setting of variables - to dummy values if required) and you've copy/pasted the **exact** results.

Comment: Assuming your code is truly as you've posted, then the most likely explanation is that `value` is not defined, so your 2nd argument is simple `""`

Comment: The thing is. When i open the cmd and run the script i dont get anything in var kommune. But if i run it again without closing the promt it shows just fine. Very wired! IMO

Comment: lol - as they said: we need the complete relevant code. I'm sure, you have the posted code inside an `if` or `for`block. Then you need delayed expansion

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact code. All of the statements are in the IF which in my opinion shouldent influence the output. You are talking about delayed expansion?

Comment: Precisely. Your omission of the `IF` statement is critical. Any variation of values made in the `(code block)` is **not** visible with `echo %var%` - you must invoke `delayedexpansion` and `echo !var!` **or** `call echo %%var%%` within the `code block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set kommune

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (q27922463.txt) DO (
    CALL :decryptLine "%%x"
)
GOTO:eof

:decryptLine
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ("%~1") do set "argument=%%a" & set "value=%%b"
set "argument=%argument:~0,-2%"
set "value=%value:~1%"
call:updateVar "%argument%" "%value%"
GOTO:EOF

:updateVar
IF "%~1" == "KommuneNavn" (
    ECHO "%~2"
    ECHO "KommuneNavn"
    set kommune=%~2
    CALL ECHO kommune = "%%kommune%%" testhest
)

GOTO :eof
```

Critical point: You haven't shown us the content of your file, so we have to construct it: **and** I've changed the filename to suit my system (`q27922463.txt`)

contents of `q27922463.txt`

```
KommuneNavnxy=yourvalue
```

output generated:

```
"ourvalue"
"KommuneNavn"
kommune = "ourvalue" testhest
```

Note the positioning of the quotes in the `set` assignments. Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

So, `%%a` becomes `KommuneNavnxy`, is assigned to `argument`, and the last 2 characters are removed, making `KommuneNavn`

Similarly, `%%b` gets `yourvalue`, you remove the first and make `ourvalue`

Since the string `kommune` is set within the code block of the `if` statement, you need to use `call echo %%var%%` to display it (one of several ways).

Comment: Okay. What is special inside the IF block? can you compare it with c or c#? im pretty confident around pointers. what does the extra pairs of %% do?

Comment: Batch is interpreted. Physical lines are loaded until a "logical line" is read ie. all parentheses are closed and the full (multi-line) statement is known. The parser then replaces all `%var%` with the value of `var` (as a *string*) at the time. In batch, `%` escapes `%` so `call set var2=%%var1%%` establishes a new `cmd` instance acting on the same environment, passing `set var2=%var1%` as a command which is then executed in the sub-process. Same argument holds for `echo`. The effect is that `%var%` is replaced by the parse-time value of `var` but `call...%%var%%` accesses the run-time value.